# How i can get Ice Cream Sandwich Layout like?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hi guys I'm trying to keep developing SMS popup under the name of SMS enhancer,I have a thread already in app section,I want change appearance of my layout, for example buttons, how I can override the " default" to edit and get ics like appearance for other devices like gb instead default? can someone help me? Or can point to some resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look into the libraries called: ActionBarSherlock?

[Home page for ActionBarSherlokc](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: well i was thinking more the "layout" not actionbar only, for example the buttons so in 2.1 i can see ICS buttons not only in 4.0+